# How to know Windows did not shutdown normally

Tags: windows, shutdown

Is there something that can tell me Windows did not shutdown normally? Like when someone has unplugged the power or pressed the hardware power button?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a log? Yes it's under administrative tools, then computer managment, event viewer. I believe it would be under system logs.

Comment: Note that on most modern machines, the "hardware" power button will just send a signal to the OS, and the OS can respond however it wants, usually by performing a normal shutdown, sleep, hibernate, or just ignoring it altogether.

Comment: ...unless you *hold* the power button, which on most systems causes a forced shutdown the OS cannot veto.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, an abnormal shutdown is recorded in the System event log during the next system boot. It will be logged with event ID 6008 from the source *Eventlog*. Here's a sample event entry:

```
Source: Event Log 
Type: Error
Description: 
The previous system shutdown at Time on
Date was unexpected.
```

**Time** and **Date** will be replaced with the time of the unexpected shutdown.

If the shutdown was caused by a Bugcheck (i.e. Blue screen error) a corresponding event ID 1001 will be logged from the source *Bugcheck*. It will contain the Stop code and some minimal additional troubleshooting data. Here's what the text of that event looks like:

> The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck. The bugcheck was: 0x00000124 (0x0000000000000000, 0xfffffa8004b19038, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000). A dump was saved in: C:\Windows\Minidump\112809-21309-01.dmp. Report Id: 112809-21309-01.

[Source](http://www.eventid.net/display-eventid-1001-source-BugCheck-eventno-10737-phase-1.htm)

You can look up the Bugcheck/Stop code (0x124 in the above example) [on MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-code-reference2) where you'll find information about each code and how to interpret the four additional parameters included with the error information.

Answer (score 4):

> A shutdown is considered abnormal if the application receives an
> immediate shut down signal from the operating system and does not get
> a chance to complete shutdown processing.

An alternative good way to get a good glimpse of what happened after an abnormal shutdown is using **Nirsoft's** [TurnedOnTimesView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/computer_turned_on_times.html).

> TurnedOnTimesView is a simple tool that analyses the event log of
> Windows operating system, and detects the time ranges that your
> computer was turned on.
>
> For every period of time that the computer was
> turned on, the following information is displayed: Startup Time,
> Shutdown Time, Duration, **Shutdown Reason**, **Shutdown Type**, **Shutdown
> Process**, and **Shutdown Code**.  TurnedOnTimesView allows you to get this
> information from your local computer, and from remote computer on your
> network if you have enough privilege to read the event log of Windows
> remotely.

[image]

*Credits: [NirSoft®](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/turnedontimesview.png)*

---

You could also use Windows Performance Analyzer and Recorder tool (from [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx))

After finished installation, run Windows Performance Recorder shortcut from the start menu.

> Set the options according to the screenshot below and click the Start
> button.
>
> - Performance scenario: Shutdown
> - Detail level: Verbose
> - Logging mode: File
> - Number of iterations: 1

[image]

> When Windows is restarted, Windows Performance Recorder will
> automatically start gathering system shutdown trace information. Once
> it is done, click the Open in WPA button.

Read More: [How To Troubleshoot Windows Startup, LogOff, Login and Shutdown Problems](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-troubleshoot-windows-startup-logoff-login-and-shutdown-problems/)